# Compare performance of libraries - test selection

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, paired-data

I am trying to perform a comparison between three implementations of the same algorithm but using different libraries. However, I am not sure about my methodology. I am measuring elapsed time as a one of the metrics. I am performing comparison on 4 datasets (sizes: 10, 100, 1000, 10000). For each combination I have 10 observations. To sum up, it looks somewhat like this:

Dataset size (10, 100, 1000, 10000)

- Library A (3ms, 500ms, 90000ms, 30000000ms)
- Library B (100ms, ...)
- Library C (10ms, ...)

I was thinking of performing pair-wise comparison for each dataset size. My first question is:
Are observations from library A - size: 10 and library B - size: 10 paired? Different sources online provide different statements about this, and from what I know this is important in choosing correct test. And is there any test that can tell me that results of Library A are not only different but also, smaller (for example). I've read about Mann–Whitney U test, but SciPy tells me that it requires at least 20 observations for each sample.
Also, I was wondering if making rank for each dataset size is the best way for doing comparison? Maybe I should take all 40 observations from library A and 40 from B, compare them together and just say that overall library A is better than B?

Comment: These are different algorithms for the same problem, yes? Then, if you feed A and B the same data/problem instance, it would be paired data. If they get unrelated input, not.

Comment: Yes, different algorithms, but everything else is the same. After some more searching I am leaning towards Wilcoxon signed-rank test as most of my results do not allow me to use t-test.